# Pass activity to LifecycleObserver

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components, lifecycleowner

I need to pass activity to a LifecycleObserver class for a location task:

```
class LocationObserver(
        private val context: Context,
        private val activity: FragmentActivity) : LifecycleObserver {
    
    private var locationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null
    private val locationListener = OnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
        if (location != null) {
            val lat = location.latitude
            val long = location.longitude
            ...
        }
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun start() {
        locationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity)
        ...
        locationClient?.lastLocation?.addOnSuccessListener(activity, locationListener)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun stop() {
        locationClient = null
    }
}
```

The LocationObserver is created and used in the fragment:

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment {
    private LocationObserver locationObserver;
    
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                       ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        locationObserver = new LocationObserver(this.getContext(), this.getActivity());
        getLifecycle().addObserver(locationObserver);
        
        return root;
    }
    ...
}
```

The question is: will pass activity to LifecycleObserver-class cause a memory leak? If so, what could be the solution? Thank you so much for any answer/comment!

Comment: How are you instantiating and using the LocationObserver?

Comment: @Ahmed I. Khalil Hi, LocationObserver is created and used in the fragment - I add to question.

Comment: Yes, holding activity reference in Your LifecycleObserver will cause memory leak. To prevent this, either you can use `LiveData` or `Callback` to provide your data back to activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if the fragment lives inside that `Activity`, probably your `Fragment` won't have a longer lifecycle, so leaks won't really occur even if you keep references to the activity.

But as long as you remove all your `Activity` references in your `LocationObserver` you can feel pretty safe.

Comment: Thank you! Please tell me where in the LocationObserver should I call: activity = null, in the onDestroy() method?